# When i am trying to run my android simulator i am getting the "Unfortunately launcher has stopped " message

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

this is my log cat.when i run my app on simulator it stops by giving message"unfortunatelt launcher has stooped"..am using API 19 4.4.2 to and APPTHEME

```
    12-15 19:45:46.180: D/AndroidRuntime(1407): Shutting down VM
    12-15 19:45:46.180: W/dalvikvm(1407): threadid=1: thread exiting    with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ae1ba8)
    12-15 19:45:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(1407): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    12-15 19:45:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(1407): Process: com.example.laundry, PID: 1407
    12-15 19:45:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(1407): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.laundry/com.example.laundry.LoginActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.laundry.LoginActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.laundry-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.laundry-2, /system/lib]]
   12-15 19:45:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
   12-15 19:45:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
   12-15 19:45:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
   12-15 19:45:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
   12-15 19:45:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   12-15 19:45:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   12-15 19:45:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
   12-15 19:45:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   12-15 19:45:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   12-15 19:45:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
   12-15 19:45:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
   12-15 19:45:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   12-15 19:45:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(1407): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.laundry.LoginActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.laundry-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.laundry-2, /system/lib]]
   12-15 19:45:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
   12-15 19:45:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
   12-15 19:45:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
   12-15 19:45:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
   12-15 19:45:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
   12-15 19:45:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):  ... 11 more
   12-15 19:45:51.210: I/Process(1407): Sending signal. PID: 1407 SIG: 9
```

here is my main activity which is.what iam trying to here is login and registration by using php my sql database

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private TextView txtName;
 private TextView txtEmail;
 private Button btnLogout;

private SQLiteHandler db;
private SessionManager session;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

    // SqLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

    // session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
        logoutUser();
    }

    // Fetching user details from sqlite
    HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

    String name = user.get("name");
    String email = user.get("email");

    txtName.setText(name);
    txtEmail.setText(email);

    // Logout button click event
    btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            logoutUser();
        }
    });
}


  private void logoutUser() {
        session.setLogin(false);
        db.deleteUsers();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

here is my manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.laundry"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:name="app.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" />
</application>
```

Here is my Login Activity

```
    package activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.example.laundry.MainActivity;
import com.example.laundry.R;
import app.AppConfig;
import app.AppController;
import helper.SQLiteHandler;
import helper.SessionManager;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private Button btnLogin;
private Button btnLinkToRegister;
private EditText inputEmail;
private EditText inputPassword;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private SessionManager session;
private SQLiteHandler db;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);

    // Progress dialog
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    // SQLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

    // Session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if user is already logged in or not
    if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
        // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    // Login button Click Event
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            // Check for empty data in the form
            if (!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                // login user
                checkLogin(email, password);
            } else {
                // Prompt user to enter credentials
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }

    });

    // Link to Register Screen
    btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });

}

/**
 * function to verify login details in mysql db
 * */
private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_login";

    pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                // Check for error node in json
                if (!error) {
                    // user successfully logged in
                    // Create login session
                    session.setLogin(true);

                    // Now store the user in SQLite
                    String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                    JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                    String name = user.getString("name");
                    String email = user.getString("email");
                    String created_at = user
                            .getString("created_at");

                    // Inserting row in users table
                    db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                    // Launch main activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // Error in login. Get the error message
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}

private void showDialog() {
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hideDialog() {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

}

Comment: please post your code   .

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: in most cases it means that Activity from package(code) doesn't fit Activity declared in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @Selvin Yes yes .You are #perfect

Comment: Yes, I know that ... also I'm humble/modest... :D

Comment: I have add my main activity also

Comment: @joseph   Post your `AndroidManifest.xml` . I guess `LoginActivity` missing

Comment: @intelliJ Amiya i have update the manifest

Comment: @intelliJ Amiya sorry before i have updater the wrong manifest i have update the correct one

Comment: Please try Clean build and look at this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810628/solved-android-unable-to-instantiate-activity-componentinfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the point .Go to your Login Activity and use this

```
package com.example.laundry
```

> http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html

Comment: @joseph  `Clean-Rebuild-Restart`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232851/class-loading-error-at-dalvik-system-basedexclassloader-findclassbasedexclasslo

Comment: Same logcat arsing ??

Comment: @joseph okay .Please post your `LoginActivity` java code

Comment: @joseph .Check my answer .